# MySQL Workbench InnoDB Buffer Usage at 100%, always

Tags: performance, mysql5.1

The InnoDB Buffer Usage graph is *always* at 100%.  I believe this started to happen when I changed MySQL's temp folder to a much bigger drive, does that make sense?

I suppose the thing to do in this situation is to try and increase the innodb buffer pool size if possible, right?

Comment: Simply restarting MySQL dropped the buffer down to 34% and it seems to be staying there.

Comment: It's a good thing to have the InnoDB Buffer Usage at 100%, and you can't make conclusion just after a restart... I learnt these things on a good answer here : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56506